# How to adjust duty cycle of an existing square-wave, based on light level

Tags: led, analog, pwm, 555, ldr

I am making a wall-powered, battery-backed, BCD alarm clock with discrete logic.

I'd like to adjust the brightness of the LEDs based on light level, as this clock will be used on a nightstand. So very low brightness in the dark, and high brightness in daylight.

The LDRs in my junk bin are about 70 ohms in bright light, and 500k in darkness.

As part of the clock oscillator, I already have 128Hz and 256Hz square waves available, which should be an appropriate PWM frequency for LEDs.

Supply voltage is about 4.6V.

For the duty-cycle adjusting, I can use a 555 timer, or general purpose transistors.

Trimpots to adjust the min and max levels would be nice.

The LEDs are wired as such, each with a 150 ohm resistor, so I'd like to switch the common GND.

[image: The LEDs are wired as such]

Comment: why are you set on a 555 or a transistor for duty cycle adjustment? It's a bit strange, you already have a clock oscillator from which you derive the 128 or 256 Hz clock, but you want to use yet another oscillator to adjust duty cycles - why?

Answer (score 1):

You need about 100:1 duty cycle range. One way is with the triangular waveform on the 555 capacitor (which is charged up and down using constant-current sources).

Have a comparator to trip on that, using an LDR-controlled voltage divider to continuously vary between VoltageMax and VoltageMin.

Answer (score 0):

The LDR full brightness and total darkness resistance values don't matter.  Since you probably do not have an LDR datasheet that relates illumination to resistance, start by measuring the LDR resistance at the brightest room illumination level where you want the dimmest display, and the resistance at the room lowest illumination level where you want the full brightness display.  These two resistance values set the range of what you have to work with in the PWM circuit.

Next is relating this resistance range to display brightness.  Commercial clock radios with this feature have a display current ratio of about 4:1 to 5:1.  My bedside clock radio has a high/low brightness switch that changes the display current by about 4:1.  your total display current probably is below 1 A, and there are many pre-built PWM modules on ebay that can handle this current.

Comment: Thanks!
Yah that's why I desired trimpots to set the brightness range.

The LEDs are rated for 20mA, and the worst case scenario will be with 16 on at once at full brightness, so I only need 320mA, and that isn't continuous. I guess I can use a PN2222A which I have plenty of.

I'd prefer to use what I have. I wouldn't be asking this question if I could just buy a PWM IC.